# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error trying to render spree collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, spree

I'm trying to show product related accessories ranked by best selling in my spree store using this:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  def best_selling_accessories
    accessories.active.select("spree_products.*, SUM(spree_line_items.quantity) AS total_qty, spree_line_items.variant_id").
    joins(:line_items).joins("INNER JOIN spree_orders ON spree_orders.id = spree_line_items.order_id").
    where("spree_orders.state = 'complete'").
    group("spree_line_items.variant_id, spree_products.id").
    order("total_qty DESC")
  end
end
```

In my controller I'm doing:

`@products = @spree_product.best_selling_accessories`

When I try to render the view though I get:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "total_qty" does not exist
LINE 1: ...line_items.variant_id, spree_products.id ORDER BY total_qty`

If I use the better errors shell and manual run the partial render:

`render "spree/shared/products", products: @products`

It returns the correct html.

Map also returns the correct results from the better errors shell:

```
>> @products.map { |p| p.total_qty }
=> [14, 10, 7, 7, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1]
```

So I'm wondering, if it renders correctly in the better errors shell and returns all the correct products when I ask for `@products`, why does activerecord throw that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to call `to_a` on the result.

I'm still confused as to why I can manually run all the commands and they return the correct result though.